# SQL - how does group by work if the group by field is a number?

Tags: sql

Given the following expression:

```
select cast(round((a) / 5) * 5 as integer) as val
       , count(case when b >= 0 then 1 
                    else null 
                end) as count_b
group by val
```

how does this use the 'val' expression to group field 'b'? The output gives:
[output_data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voX3s.png)

Is this being grouped based on whether it is > val, or < val, or between adjacent vals?

Answer (score 1):

In databases that support aliases in the `group by`, it is the same as repeating the expression:

```
group by cast(round((a) / 5) * 5 as integer)
```

This is basically rounding values to the nearest multiple of 5.  So, values such as 5, 5.1, and 6.2 are all in the group for "5".